# Loops within loops

Tags: ansible

I've set up some application information in my Ansible `group_vars` like this:

```
applications:
  - name: app1
  - name: app2
  - name: app3
  - name: app4
    settings:
      log_dir: /var/logs/app4
      associated_files:
        - auth/key.json
  - name: app5
    settings:
      log_dir: /var/logs/app5
      repo_path: new_apps/app5
```

I'm struggling to get my head around how I can use these "sub loops".

My tasks for each application are:

1. Create some folders based purely on the `name` value
2. Create a log folder if a `settings/log_dir` value exists
3. Copy associated files over, if specified

The syntax for these tasks isn't the problem here, I'm comfortable with those - I just need to know how to access the information from this `applications` variable. Number **3** in particular seems troublesome to me - I need to loop within a loop.

To debug this, I've been trying to run the following task:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ applications }}"
    - settings
```

Here's the output:

- `with_items`: I get the error `with_items expects a list or a set`
- `with_nested`: I can see the top level information (e.g. `msg: {{ item }}` outputs an array of `app1`, `app2` etc)
- `with_subelements`: I get the error `subelements lookup expects a dictionary, got 'None'`

It's possible/probable that the way I've set the variable up in the first instance is wrong. If there's a better way to do this, it's not a problem to change it.

Comment: What is the structure of `rundeck_python_scripts` ? What is the relation with the `applications` data structure your referenced ? Moreover, the yaml you pasted for your example task is not valid.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's what happens when you try to make a generic comprehension out of a real script for the purposes of posting on Stack Overflow :) Will fix OP now.

Comment: Done - apologies again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `with_subelements` because `settings` is a dictionary, not a list. If you were to restructure your data so that `settings` is a list, like this:

```
applications:
  - name: app1
  - name: app2
  - name: app3
  - name: app4
    settings:
      - name: log_dir
        value: /var/logs/app4
      - name: associated_files
        value:
          - auth/key.json
  - name: app5
    settings:
      - name: log_dir
        value: /var/logs/app5
      - name: repo_path
        value: new_apps/app5
```

You could then write something like the following to iterate over each setting for each application:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - applications.yml
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "set {{ item.1.name }} to {{ item.1.value }} for {{ item.0.name }}"
      loop: "{{ applications|subelements('settings', skip_missing=true) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.name }}.{{ item.1.name }} = {{ item.1.value }}"
```

(I'm using `loop_control` here just to make the output nicer.)

Using the sample data you posted in `applications.yml`, this will produce as output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=app4.log_dir = /var/logs/app4) => {
    "msg": "set log_dir to /var/logs/app4 for app4"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=app4.associated_files = ['auth/key.json']) => {
    "msg": "set associated_files to ['auth/key.json'] for app4"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=app5.log_dir = /var/logs/app5) => {
    "msg": "set log_dir to /var/logs/app5 for app5"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=app5.repo_path = new_apps/app5) => {
    "msg": "set repo_path to new_apps/app5 for app5"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks for this @larsks, this is definitely a step in the right direction.

If I wanted to loop through just the `associated_files` values for each `application`, how would I do this in your example? Would I have to apply some kind of logic to the `settings` list to filter only `name==associated_files`?

Comment: Now you're asking for a third level of iteration, which becomes increasingly complicated. I would move `associated_files` up one level so that it is no longer a child of `settings`, and then just handle it the same way you handle `settings`.